# Code that compiled in ubuntu but not working in win 7

Tags: texmaker, windows, ubuntu

I was typing my thesis in ubuntu in gedit and compiling in the terminal and it worked fine but now due to some reasons I installed windows 7 in my PC but the same code is not working in texmaker. When I compile my code I see these errors.

**Error-1-** line 11- command \proof already defined.

**Error-2**  line22- \qed already defined.

Here is my (sample) code-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={5in, 10in}]{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][Example]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\newcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
  \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
  \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
  \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}

\begin{document}

\title{An Introduction to Differential Algebra-(Notes)}
\author{Jagdeep Singh}

\maketitle
\section{GENERALITIES CONCERNING DIFFERENTIAL RINGS}

\subsection{Derivations}
\begin{definition} - A derivation of a ring A is an additive mapping $ a \mathbb{\to} a'$ of A into itself satisfying 

$$ (ab)' = a'b + ab' $$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey. Do you have the same versions of texlive/MikTex installed and the same package versions? Further, change `\newenvironment{proof}` to `\renewenvironment{proof}` and `\newcommand{\qed}` to `\renewcommand{\qed}`. Since both already exist, latex simply does not overwrite the existing definitions without a warning.

Comment: Your code is failing with an updated TL2015, so either you have a very old TeX distro in your Ubuntu machine or your editor is simply ignoring errors and forcing compilation.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT Yes I have Miktex installed... and I have most packages installed. plz suggest which one I need for this sample so I can check them.

Comment: i can't believe that this actually worked on any system.  `proof` and `\qed` have been defined for decades in `amsthm`, so perhaps you added `amsthm` when you switched systems?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am using "\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}" in preamble in texmaker in windows. Isnt it fine?

Comment: @barbarabeeton the same code is working in sharelatex too...

Comment: these packages are all fine, but since `amsthm` defines `proof` and `\qed`, either you didn't load `amsthm` on the old system, or you have added these new definitions when you changed systems, or you ignored error messages on the old system.  there are no other possibilities.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes. Ubuntu ignored these errors... but now I am looking for how to avoid these errors in windows

Comment: Replace `\newcommand{\qed}` with `\renewcommand`, and `\newenvironment{proof}` with `\renewenvironment`, or simply remove these definitions

Comment: @Au101 I tried it but it still not working. Ii am not much familiar with coding or tex, if you may please reedit my code as an answer it ll be much clearer to me. Really need help here.

Comment: no ubunto and windows are not relevant here, tex works the same way you must have just scrolled past the errors, which you could do in either system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As barbara beeton has pointed out in the comments, the problem is that `amsthm` defines `proof` and `\qed`. Therefore, when you load `amsthm` and then have:

```
\newcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
  \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
  \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
  \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}
```

This is a problem, because

```
Command \qed already defined.
```

In other words, how can you define a new command `\qed`, when `\qed` is already defined? You can't. You need to **re**-define it, thus:

```
\renewcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
  \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
  \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
  \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}
```

Similarly

```
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
```

**For me,**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={5in, 10in}]{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
    \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][Example]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\renewcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
  \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
  \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
  \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}

\begin{document}

\title{An Introduction to Differential Algebra-(Notes)}
\author{Jagdeep Singh}

\maketitle
\section{GENERALITIES CONCERNING DIFFERENTIAL RINGS}

\subsection{Derivations}
\begin{definition} - A derivation of a ring A is an additive mapping
  $ a \mathbb{\to} a'$ of A into itself satisfying

$$ (ab)' = a'b + ab' $$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Compiles fine.

[image]

However, [you should avoid `$$ ... $$` in LaTeX and replace them with `\[ ... \]`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

You should also remove the blank line before the displayed equation:

```
\begin{definition} - A derivation of a ring A is an additive mapping
  $ a \mathbb{\to} a'$ of A into itself satisfying    
  \[
    (ab)' = a'b + ab'
  \]
\end{definition}
```

I also genuinely don't understand what you're trying to accomplish by wrapping `\to` in `\mathbb{}` but you've destroyed the binary spacing around the arrow, is this intentional?